# Observation from localization that $M_\mathfrak{p} \neq 0$ iff there exists $x \neq 0$ in $M$ s.t. $\mathrm{Ann}(x) \subseteq \mathfrak{p}$

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

In the notes by J.P. May, it is said that “the definition of localization implies the following observation:”

> Lemma $0.3.$ $M_\mathfrak{p} \neq 0$ iff there exists $x \neq 0$ in $M$ s.t. $\mathrm{Ann}(x) \subseteq \mathfrak{p}$. Therefore $\mathrm{Ass}(M)$ is contained in $\mathrm{Supp}(M)$.

I am only trying to understand the forward direction. Note that any nonzero $x \in M$ whose image in $M_\mathfrak{p}$ is nonzero would work for $x$. How does the definition of localization imply that $\mathrm{Ann}(x) \subseteq \mathfrak{p}$?

My attempt at showing that $\mathrm{Ann}(x) \subseteq \mathfrak{p}$ is by contradiction from other cases where $\mathrm{Ann}(x) \nsubseteq \mathfrak{p}$ which forces the latter option:

Case $\mathrm{Ann}(x) \cap \mathfrak{p} = \emptyset$: Then elements of $\mathrm{Ann}(x)$ are invertible in $M_\mathfrak{p}$, hence let $a \in \mathrm{Ann}(x)$ and we have $\frac{x}{1} = \frac{a x}{a} = \frac{0}{1}$, a contradiction by our choice of $x$.

Case $\mathrm{Ann}(x) \cap \mathfrak{p} \neq \emptyset$ but $\mathrm{Ann}(x) \nsubseteq \mathfrak{p}$: This is similar to the previous case, except let $b \in \mathrm{Ann}(x) \setminus \mathfrak{p}$, it is clear that exists such $b$ and hence this $b$ is invertible in $M_\mathfrak{p}$, so by the same proof as above replacing $a$ by $b$, we arrive at a contradiction.

This shows $\mathrm{Ann}(x) \subseteq \mathfrak{p}$. Is there a better way of seeing this fact from the definition of localization?

Ref: J.P. May’s notes on ‘Associated Prime Ideals’ [http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/MISC/AssoPrimes.pdf](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/MISC/AssoPrimes.pdf)

Comment: Try looking at the contrapositive: if $\text{Ann}(x)\subsetneq p$, prove that x=0$ in $M_p$.

Comment: @NathanLowry Sure, I can do the same proof: Consider the canonical map $M \to M_\mathfrak{p},$ $m \mapsto \frac{m}{1}$. If Ann($x$) $\not\subset \mathfrak{p}$, then there exists $b \in $ Ann($x$)$\backslash \mathfrak{p}$, hence $x$ via the canonical map give $\frac{x}{1} = \frac{bx}{b} = \frac{0}{b}$, hence $x = 0$ in $M_\mathfrak{p}.$